# Show that there is an infinite $L$-structure that satisfies $\alpha$

Tags: logic

I struggle with this question

Fix a first order language $L$ and let $\alpha$ be an $L$-sentence. Suppose that for every $N \in \mathbb N$ there is an $L$-structure with at least $N$ elements that satisfies α. Show that there is an infinite $L$-structure that satisfies $\alpha$. (using the completeness theorem)

any help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Have you learned the compactness theorem?

Comment: yes I learned about it already.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varphi_n$ be the sentence "there exist at least $n$ elements in the universe of the structure," namely
$$\exists x_1 \exists x_2 \dots \exists x_n \bigwedge_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} x_i \neq x_j$$
Then consider the $L$-theory defined as $\alpha \cup \bigcup_{1 < n < \omega} \varphi_n$. Can you finish the proof?

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Did you mean that the -theory you constructed satisfies , then you can conclude that there are infinite -structure satisfies ?

Comment: actually, I don't understand how we can apply completeness theorem in this case

Comment: @Shady2107 Once you conclude that a theory is satisfiable, you need to invoke completeness to say it has a model.

Comment: @Shady2107 And yes, this theory entails $\alpha$, and therefore any model if it will satisfy $\alpha$. You need to show (a) this theory has models (why is it satisfiable?), and (b) any model of this theory must be infinite.

Comment: for (a) I would just say since the L-theory is consistent then it is satisfiable (as the compactness theorem).

Comment: I meant by the completeness thoerm

Comment: But I am not sure for (b)

Comment: @Shady2107 How are you showing this theory is consistent? And perhaps try contradiction for the infinitude of the models.